# Create table error oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting an error: ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns

when trying to create a table from data in 2 other tables. Please help, is this just a syntax error or am I combining the tables in the wrong way?

```
CREATE TABLE EMPDATA(ID, NAME, SALARY, DEPTNAME)
AS
   SELECT e.employee_id, (e.first_name || e.last_name), e.salary  
   FROM employees e
   UNION
   SELECT d.department_name 
   FROM departments d;
```

Comment: You need to `join` to set the department and not `union`

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `JOIN` instead of `UNION`:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPDATA(ID, NAME, SALARY, DEPTNAME)
AS
   SELECT e.employee_id, (e.first_name || e.last_name), e.salary, d.department_name
   FROM employees e
   JOIN departments d on(d.department_id = e.department_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

The number of coumns while using UNION should be same in the SELECT statement

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `join` to set the department and not `union`

```
CREATE TABLE EMPDATA(ID, NAME, SALARY, DEPTNAME)
AS
   SELECT e.employee_id, (e.first_name || e.last_name), e.salary, d.department_name 
   FROM employees e
   JOIN departments d on d.id = e.department_id
```

You might need to adjust the column names of the `join` condition since you did not mention the relation.

Answer (score 1):

Your `select` query returns three columns, for the table you want four. `union` does union the results of queries, but they have to have same number and types of columns. Your second query has one column, first - three.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a table from a subquery, the resulting columns must be of the same type and number of columns as the subquery.

It is not worth having an EMPLOYEE_ID column of type NUMBER in the DDL and having the column EMPLOYEE_ID of type DATE for example.

Maybe the column exists in the DDL and the subquery DOES NOT EXIST.
in your example you try to have the column DEPTNAME in the DDL, but in the subquery that column does not exist in the table EMPLOYEES,
If you want to have the column DEPTNAME, you have to do a JOIN with the table DEPARTMENTS.

Remaining as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPDATA (ID, NAME, SALARY, DEPTNAME) AS
   SELECT e.employee_id, (e.first_name || e.last_name), e.salary, d.department_name
   FROM employees e,
        departments d
   WHERE 1 = 1
   AND d.department_id = e.department_id;
```

In my BLOG I have an article that talks about the DDL [CREATE TABLE statement in ORACLE SQL](https://mariocelis.com/sql/create-table/), I'll share it for you.

There I talk about a little more things, like creating primary, foreign, insert, etc. klaves.